# Wrap a Postgres Json Array in a Json object

Tags: json, postgresql

When I execute

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(curriculum_overview))) 
FROM study.curriculum_overview;
```

On a predefined view I have I get something similar to this

`[{"study_programme":"SE","semester":1,"module_code":"B1"},...}]`

I want this array wrapped in an object, and possibly add some metadata like a timestamp to it, example:

```
{
    timeStamp: now,
    data: [{...},{...},{...}]
}
```

How is this possible using a query? Or do I have to do this in a client and modify the data after obtaining the query results?

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: I want to wrap the JSON Array that Postgres gives me in a JSON Object using a query.

Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231422/how-to-wrap-json-output-in-array-with-postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function [`json_build_object(),`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    json_build_object(
        'timestamp', now(), 
        'metadata', 'some_value',
        'data', array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(co))))
FROM study.curriculum_overview co;
```